uniqueness of a projection of a vector
Let $W$ a $k$-dimentional subspace of a finite dimensional inner product vector space $V$. If $v\in V$, then it is well known that the vector
$$
p=\langle v,w_1\rangle w_1+\ldots+\langle v,w_k\rangle w_k,
$$
where $\{w_1,\ldots,w_k\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $W$, is the "closest" vector to $v$ on $W$, in the sense that
$$
\min\{\|v-w\|:w\in W\}=\|v-p\|
$$
My question: Why $p$ is unique? that is, why there is no other vector, say $q\in W$, such that
$$
\min\{\|v-w\|:w\in W\}=\|v-q\|\quad ?
$$

What do you mean? You literally wrote down a formula for $p$. How can it not be unique if it is obtained through a formula?

I claim that the vector $p$ satisfies $\min{|v-w|:w\in W}=|v-p|$ and that this $p$ is given by the formula above. My question is why there is no other vector, say $q$, such that $\min{|v-w|:w\in W}=|v-q|$.

So I guess that $p$ is not the closest vector but a closest vector for you? Anyway, if you know about orthogonal projection, then $p$ is the orthogonal projection of $v$ onto $W$. For any vector $q\in W$, $v-q = (v-p)+(p-q)$ with $p-q$ orthogonal to $v-p$. The result then comes from Pythagore.

@boaz If you haven’t seen orthogonal projections, this also follows from parallelogram law. Namely, this follows from the claim that any convex set in an inner product space has at most one vector of minimal norm, as $v-W$ is a convex set. To prove the claim, assume $p,q\in A$ both have minimal norms in $A$ and $A$ is convex. Then by parallelogram law,$$|p-q|^2=2|x|^2+2|y|^2-|p+q|^2=4\min_{h\in A}|h|^2-4|\frac{p+q}{2}|^2\leq 4\min_{h\in A}|h|^2-4\min_{h\in A}|h|^2=0$$So, $p=q$. (This is one step in constructing orthogonal projections in general Hilbert spaces, actually.)

Thanks @David Gao 1

Define orthonormal matrix $A=[w_1,\dots,w_k] \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$. The problem becomes solving
$$\min_{{x}\in \mathbb{R}^k}\, \|Ax-v\|_2^2 \implies x^{*} = (A^{\top}A)^{-1}A^{\top}v = A^{\top}v$$
$$p=Ax^{*} = [w_1,\dots,w_k]
\begin{bmatrix}
\langle v,w_1\rangle \\
\vdots \\
\langle v,w_k\rangle
\end{bmatrix} = \sum_{I=1}^k \langle v,w_i\rangle w_i$$
Since the objective of the minimization problem is strong convex, $x^*$ is unique, so is $p$.
Alternatively, suppose there is another $q$ yielding minimum distance, we have
$\|−\|=\|(−)+(−)\|\leq \|−\|+\|−\| = \|−\| \implies \|−\| = 0 \implies p=q$.

Instead of <,> , please use \langle , \rangle . Otherwise, nice answer.
